# Compiler error: failed to bind overloaded function with two arguments

Tags: c++

I can't find a way to make my following code compile. I'm looking for a way to bind the first overloaded sn() which takes an enum, such that I can just pass a string to it. I don't need to bind the second overloaded.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Stats
{
    enum AlignMetrics
    {
        AlignExon,
        AlignIntron,
        AlignBase
    };

    // How to bind this function??
    inline double sn(const std::string &cID, enum AlignMetrics m) const
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    inline double sn(const std::string &cID, const std::string &id) const
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Stats stats;

    // Ok (calling directly)        
    stats.sn("", Stats::AlignMetrics::AlignExon);

    // Can't compile (I want to bind it such that it takes only the first argument)
    std::bind(static_cast<double (Stats::*)(const std::string &, enum Stats::AlignMetrics)>(&Stats::sn), &stats, std::placeholders::_1, Stats::AlignMetrics::AlignExon);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler and standard are you using?  I never seen `enum` used in-line with arguments like that...    In C++11 you can create an `enum class E{ e1, e2 }` and access to an enumeration requires using `E::*` scope.  Then just have `void function(E e)` as the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `const`:

```
std::bind(static_cast<double (Stats::*)(const std::string &, enum Stats::AlignMetrics) const>(&Stats::sn), &stats, std::placeholders::_1, Stats::AlignMetrics::AlignExon);
                                                                                     // ^^^ Missing
```

Suggestion for simplification:

```
double (Stats::*fptr)(const std::string &, enum Stats::AlignMetrics) const = &Stats::sn;
std::bind(fptr, &stats, std::placeholders::_1, Stats::AlignMetrics::AlignExon);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda:

```
auto func = [&](std::string const &s) { return stats.sn(s, Stats::AlignMetrics::AlignExon); };
```